# Pending Intents with extras not working when calling Alarm Manager

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

I have looked at many examples here of people having a similar problem with passing extras, but I still don't see my problem.

Here is my code where I set up my extras:

```
            PLAY_MUSIC = "Y";
        Intent intentAlarm = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intentAlarm.putExtra("playMusic",PLAY_MUSIC);
        intentAlarm.putExtra("mPos", mPos);
        // 12345 is a request code
        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 12345, 
                intentAlarm, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)(this.getSystemService( Context.ALARM_SERVICE ));
        am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calSet.getTimeInMillis(), pIntent );
```

Here is where I am getting them in onCreate()

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (VERBOSE) Log.v(TAG, "+++ ON CREATE +++");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);        

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    playMusicFlag = intent.getStringExtra("playMusic"); 
    mPos = intent.getIntExtra("mPos", 0);
    if (playMusicFlag == "Y") {
        if (VERBOSE) Log.v(TAG, "+++ playMusicFlag NOT SET+++");
        playSongs();
        showStopAlarmButton();
    } // if
```

playMusicFlag doesn't get set. playSongs and showStopAlarm are not called. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: I think strings comprassion is the problem here. Try to compare strings using `equals` method `if ("Y".equals(playMusicFlag))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Log your `playMusicFlag` String and check indeed are you getting any value and then compare your string;

this way:

```
if (playMusicFlag.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"))
```

Instead:

```
if (playMusicFlag == "Y")
```

Comment: Thanks! The comparison worked great. My fields were null after I got the statement correct, due to the fact that I was checking the values in onCreate and not in onResume.Hopefully, this can help someone else as well.

Answer (score -1):

use like this while retriving

```
intent.getExtras().getString("playMusic");
```

i think it works.